# Default Header OpenAPI 3.0 | Java Jaxrs-RestEasy

Tags: java, swagger, jax-rs, openapi

In my project all endpoints recives 3 default headers params. **I would like to define this just once**. Now I'm just setting this 3 params to every endpoint

```
@Parameter(name = "app-key", in = ParameterIn.HEADER, required = true, schema = @Schema(type = "string"))
@Parameter(name = "other-key", in = ParameterIn.HEADER, required = true, schema = @Schema(type = "string"))
@Parameter(name = "other-key", in = ParameterIn.HEADER, required = true, schema = @Schema(type = "string"))
```

Comment: for this, you can create a common request  handler for all the APIs